# Question on what constitutes surfaces in R3

Tags: differential-geometry, surfaces

Our lecturer gave us the following definition of a surface in $\mathbb{R}^3$:
$\Gamma$ Is a surface in $\mathbb{R}^3$ if for all $y\in \Gamma$ there exists a coordinate patch $\sigma : D\subset\mathbb{R}^2 \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^3$ such that $y \in \text{Im}(\sigma)\subset\Gamma$.  From this definition, is it not inferred that the union of two surfaces is a surface? I am confused because he went on to mention that the union of the boundary of the unit sphere and the set $\{(x,y,0)|x^2+y^2<1\}$ is not a surface. Clearly these are both surfaces so why isn’t their union?

Comment: The union of two surfaces is hardly ever a surface.

Comment: If the two surfaces are disjoint then their union may be a surface. Not connected but still a surface. Did your definition mention connectedness?

Comment: Nothing about connectedness, no

Comment: Depending on what you mean by coordinate patch, this is the definition of an embedded surface, or of an immersed surface, or even something else.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $S$ be the unit sphere $\{(x, y, z) \mid x^2+y^2+z^2=1\}$ and $T = \{(x, y, 0) \mid x^2 +y^2<1\}$ be the two surfaces you mention and let $\Gamma = S \cup T$. Then the point $e = (1, 0, 0)$ in $\Gamma$ has no neighbourhood in $U$ that is homeomorphic with an open set $D$ of $\Bbb{R}^2$. To prove this takes a little work, but it should be clear visually: any neighbourhood of $e$ in $\Gamma$ looks locally like the union along their edges of three half-planes and no open subset of $\Bbb{R}^2$ looks like that.

Comment: So must the definition be ammended so that $\text{Im}(\sigma)$ must contain a neighbourhood of every point of $\Gamma$?

Comment: I've changed the notation in my answer to match yours better. The definitions don't need changing. What I am saying is that there can't be a coordinate patch that maps to an open subset of $\Gamma$ containing the point $e$.

Comment: I mean the definition in my question. The condition that it maps to an ‘open subset of’ $\Gamma$ isn’t implied by the definition in the original question

Comment: Or maybe I’m misunderstanding the implications of being mapped onto by a coordinate patch

Comment: I was assuming your definition of coordinate patch was a homeomorphism between an open subset of $\\Bbb{R}^2$ and a neighbourhood in $\Gamma$ (and if you have one of those, you can find a slight smaller coordinate patch that gives a homeomorphism with an **open** neighbourhood in $\Gamma$). To go into this in more detail, you need to tell us exactly what definition of "coordinate patch" you are using.

Comment: The definition was as follows: $\sigma : D \subset \mathbb{R}^2\rightarrow \mathbb{R}^3$ is a coordinate patch if D is open and $\sigma$ is regular, smooth and injective.

Comment: In that case, the definitions you are working with are obviously wrong (which I think was your point in the first place). No reasonable definition of surface (perhaps allowing for self-intersections or singularies of various sorts) allows $\Bbb{R}^3$ itself to be considered as a surface, but the definition you have been given does. $\ddot{\frown}$.

Comment: Ok, just needed to be sure that I wasn’t just misunderstanding the ideas. Thanks for all your help!

Comment: Do please come back with comments or an answer to let us know what your lecturer really meant to say.